# How do I translate the C# Google Spreadsheet API example into f#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

The exaple code from [google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet) is

```cs
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream =
        new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "../.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }

    // Create Google Sheets API service.
    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
    // continuing
```

my attempt to translate it into f# is ([link](https://github.com/fbehrens/fbsol/blob/master/fsheets/Program.fs))

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let  Scopes = [| SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly |]
    let  ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart"
    let credPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, 
                                "../.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json")
    use stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    let credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                      Scopes,
                      "user",
                      CancellationToken.None,
                      new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result
    let service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer(),
                                      ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                                      HttpClientInitializer = credential)
```

it fails with the error message

```
Method 'set_ApplicationName' is not accessible from this code location  fsheets C:\db\code\visualstudio\fbsol\fsheets\Program.fs    30
```

I have the project with running c# and my f# on https://github.com/fbehrens/fbsol.git

What am I missing. How does this translate correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are passing in `ApplicationName` and `HttpClientInitializer` and parameters into the constructor of `SheetsService`. The C# code instead passes in those parameters in the constructor of the `BaseClientService`. This is how you might do it in F#.

```
let baseService = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
baseService.ApplicationName  <- ApplicationName
baseService.HttpClientInitializer <- credential
let service = new SheetsService(baseService)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I should have seen this. I didn't know about the {} in c#. I gues the `using () {}` construct disposes the 'var steam' after the code block, right ?